# How to download the CSV result of the same Data Explorer query agains different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

I want to save the result of the same query done on using Data Explorer using a script but it doesn't seem to work properly because I get the same set of results.

```
wget -q --timestamp http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/csv/73895  -O data-active-users-superuser.csv
wget -q --timestamp http://data.stackexchange.com/apple/csv/73895  -O data-active-users-apple.csv
```

Note: I need a scriptable solution :)

Comment: After executing that, both files are empty for me apart from the headings.  Same for direct download in the browser.  The respective query URLs seem to work, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get the CSV files of [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73895/active-users-by-year-month), you're using the wrong URL. The correct one (for the current version of the query) would be:

```
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/82441
```

Swapping in the appropriate site names in the URL should produce the right results for each site.

Also, I'm not sure that script-based access to the CSV files is necessarily an intended use-case, so I'd recommend against requesting the results for too many queries too quickly.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the URL of the latest version of a query? Or the only way to link is to a specific version?

Comment: You have to request the results of a specific revision. Since you don't necessarily know what changed between revisions without checking for yourself, using a particular manually-selected revision seems like the safer approach anyway.